# forcing droid sans to use as font in application

Tags: android, fonts

I have an android application in which if user changes his/her system font through settings to some other font, it looks ugly, how can I force my application to use droid sans as default font or an individual element to use droid sans irrespective of user preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the XML layout to set the font for your application via `android:typeface`. You can set it to `normal`, `sans`, `serif`, or `monospace`.

Comment: I already did that , it's not working if user selects another font from android settings application

Comment: you cannot force it, just suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Put font file to project '/assets' folder and use it this way:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_text);
    text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "DroidSans.ttf"));
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without getting a copy of DroidSans.ttf so we don't have to deal with copyright license? shouldn't DroidSans.ttf be available directly with the Android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

In `styles.xml`, go to your **Base application theme** definition and then force typeface to use **sans**. So it will be something like below

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>
```